# SQL. Как сделать поиск с несколькими значениями?

Tags: php, sql

При таком запросе: И при поиске одного значения

```
SELECT * 
FROM resources
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=resources.author_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.categories_id=resources.categories_id
LEFT JOIN specialty ON specialty.specialty_id=resources.specialty_id
WHERE
    categories.categories LIKE '%$_GET[categories]%' AND title LIKE '%$_POST[search]%'
    OR
    categories.categories LIKE '%$_GET[categories]%' AND description LIKE '%$_POST[search]%'
    OR .......
```

все нормально, но если искать более одного значения то ничего не находит.

ВОПРОС: Как сделать так чтобы при запросе Например: СЛОВО СЛОВО все находилось ?)

Comment: дак у вас в базе есть сочетание `слово слово` с одним пробелом между ними то?

Comment: разбиваешь search на массив, дальше циклом формируешь `LIKE` , чтоб получилось `title LIKE '%$splittedArray[0]%' OR title LIKE ''%$splittedArray[0]% .....'` и вставляешь в запрос

Comment: уточните, вам надо чтобы искалось оба слова в названии/описании, или хотя бы одно из них.

Comment: надо чтобы находил автора не только по Имени Или Фамилий, но и по Фамилия Имя, а в БД  Ф.И.О  разделены по отдельным столбам

Comment: добавьте к запросу `or 1=1` тогда будет всё находиться